# Is it possible to compare a Java list to a JavaScript one?

Tags: java, javascript, json, protractor

I am testing an Angular JS application.
My search test compare a web element list to a Java List.
The Java list is created by calling a REST API getting a JSON response then extract the needed data from the JSON response.
As my front end is using angular JS I have ised protractor to get the UI data so my tests are written in JavaScript.
Is it possible to call my Java method inside my JavaScript test in order to compare the Java List to a Web element list created through a protractor test?

Comment: I don't understand your application architecture ? An angular front-end and a java backend ?

Comment: Yes my application has an angular front end so I have opted for protractor to test the UI. Whereas I have already written a program in Java that extract some data by calling a REST api and extracting specefic data from a JSON response.

Comment: You can't invoke directly a java method from javascript, but i think you can invoke a java program. http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at it and let you know.